# jquery enable and disable

Tags: jquery

I added a disable/enable feature but the select menus are always disabled. I would like to enable them based on whether or not a user clicks a check box. User reply check box enables `#usernames` and text effects check box enables `#boxcode, #colors`.

Also I have a clear function I want to use to remove the values from `#display, #message, #names, #boxcode` but it doesn't do anything when the button is clicked.

Jquery

```
function userreply() {
    $('#display').text('startreply ' + 'middlereply ' + $('#usernames').val() + ' endreply ' + $('#message').val());
    $("input:checkbox").click(function() {
        $("#usernames").attr("disabled", !this.checked);
    });
}

function texteffect() {
    $('#display').text('starttag '
    $('#message').val() + ' endtag ' + $('#boxcode').val());
    $("input:checkbox").click(function() {
        $("#boxcode, #colors").attr("disabled", !this.checked);
    });
}

function clear() {
    $('#display, #message, #names, #boxcode').reset();
}

$('#message').keyup(userreply);
$('#usernames').change(userreply);
$('#boxcode').change(texteffect);
```

HTML

```
<form>
    <input type="checkbox" name="enableuserreply" onclick="enable_text(this.checked)" /> Enable User Reply<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="enapletexteffect" onclick="enable_text(this.checked)" /> Enable Text Effect<br />
    <select id="usernames" disabled="disabled">
        <option value="">Users</option>
        <option value="Alex">Alex</option>
        <option value="Jeff">Jeff</option>
        <option value="Amy">Amy</option>
        <option value="Kate">Kate</option>
    </select>
    <select id="boxcode" disabled="disabled">
        <option value="">Codes</option>
        <option value="[b][/b]">Bold</option>
        <option value="[i][/i]">Italics</option>
        <option value="[u][/u]">underline </option>
        <option value="[s][/s]">Strike</option>
        <option value="[sup][/sup]">Super Script</option>
        <option value="[sub][/sub]">Sub Script</option>
        <option value="[center][/center]">Center</option>
        <option value="[big][/big]">Big</option>
        <option value="[small][/small]">Small</option>
        <option value="[br]">Line Break</option>
        <option value="[url=][/url]">Link</option>
        <option value="startpicture endpicture">Picture</option>
        <option value="[color=][/color]">Color</option>
    </select>
    <select id="colors" disabled="disabled">
        <option value="">Color</option>
        <option value="red">red</option>
        <option value="blue">blue</option>
        <option value="green">green</option>
        <option value="white">white</option>
    </select>
    <input id="message" type="text" />
    <input type="button" value="Clear" onclick="clear()" />
</form>

<pre id="display"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for your enable disable problem have a look at [this JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kwicher/ypmfK/2/).

I changed checkboxes names to ids and completely rewrote the click handlers to work with jQuery 1.6.

BTW there were quite many syntax errors in your code :)

Have fun

K

Comment: amazing!! that is exactly what i am look for. can you show me how to add this `$('#display').text('startreply ' + 'middlereply ' + $('#usernames').val() + ' endreply ' + $('#message').val());` i would like to add the values to the pre element based on the users selections

Comment: For your #display message you need to add the handler to form e.g. `$('form').change(function(){
$('#display').text('startreply ' + 'middlereply ' +   $('#usernames option:selected').val() + ' endreply ' + $('#message').val());   
    });`

Answer (score 0):

`change` has problems in IE try using `live` like `$('#usernames').live("change", userreply);`

I doubt if you can reset the `SELECT` using reset. You can reset the form which will reset all elements in it. `$('#formId')[0].reset();// OR just this.form.reset()`

If you want to save some elements on the form then just store their value, reset form, set the values stored back.